# Call to undefined method stdClass::isEmpty() error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to check if the $pl1 is empty but it does not seems to work. I tried using count() but does not seems to work either.

controller:

```
$paperlist1 =   DB::table('upload_papers')
                        ->join('courselist','courselist.id', '=', 'upload_papers.courselist_id')
                        ->join('users','users.id','=','upload_papers.upload_by')
                        ->select('upload_papers.file_name','upload_papers.paper_no','upload_papers.path','users.role_id')
                        ->where([
                            ['courselist.faculty_id','=',$facultyid],
                            ['upload_papers.courselist_id','=',$id],
                            ['upload_papers.paper_no','=',1]
                            ])
                        ->get();
```

blade.php:

```
<tr>
@foreach($paperlist1 as $pl1)
                    @if(!$pl1 -> isEmpty())
                        @if($pl1->role_id === 2)
                        <td><a href="/{{ $pl1->path }}">{{ $pl1->file_name }}</a></td>
                        @else
                        <td>-</td>
                        @endif
                        @if($pl1->role_id === 3)
                        <td><a href="/{{ $pl1->path }}">{{ $pl1->file_name }}</a></td>
                        @else
                        <td>-</td>
                        @endif
                      </tr>
                        @break
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$paperlist1` is the Collection, so `->isEmpty()` will only work on `$paperlist1` and not on `$pl1` as `$pl1` is each value of the collection.

So, `@if(!$pl1 -> isEmpty())` (that could be more readable if you used `@if($pl1->isNotEmpty())`) will not make sense at all, because you already have data.

Comment: that makes sense i think i understand but then how do you check each value of collection?

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: I want to check if $pl1 is empty

Comment: `$pl1` is not going to be empty, it is a value gathered from the DB, that is why it is on the collection (`$paperlist1`). so `$pl1` is 100% sure to have data, it is NOT going to be empty NEVER (based in your SQL query).

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. Hope you have a great day :)

Comment: My pleasure! Remember to check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table).